# handling undefined values in bottle's SimpleTemplate Engine templates

Tags: python, templates, bottle

How can I handle this:

```
... value="{{thing['attr']}}" ...
```

as '' for an undefined thing?
I tried

```
... value="{{thing['attr'] if node else ''}}" ...
```

but it complains, that thing is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{thing['attr'] if defined('thing') else ''}}
```